# Do shield boosters benefit cloaking modules?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

Shield boosters increase the max shield buffer but I am not noticing any changes/benefits when using the cloaking module with shield boosters. Is there a different booster for cloaking?

(Shields and Cloaks both use the shield slot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a different booster. You need Cloak Booster Module, which provides following benefits:

- Cloak Strength +20%
- Cloak Regen Speed +20%
- Cloak Recharge Time -20%
- Cloak Disruption Time -20% (invisibility time lost to shooting or
  getting hit)¨

Source(s):

- http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Cloak_Booster_Module
- http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/